# Third isomorphism theorem, about quotients

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces

I'm trying to understand the third isomorphism theorem statement, specifically the one in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem
I'm stuck at the point (1) because I don't agree with the statement, it doesn't make sense to me that:

> If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $N \subseteq K \subseteq G$, then
>   $K/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$.

The single fact that bugs me is that you can't say that $K/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$, because to be a subgroup you must be  subset, and satisfy certain axioms... but $K/H$ it's not even a subset of G/H? I don't see how one is a subset of the other. We know $K$ is a subset of $G$, that doesn't imply, to me, that $K/N$ is a subset of $G/N$, in any obvious way. I did a lot of exercises about groups, I need help understanding this fact.

Sorry for the latex, I really don't know it, I just copied the phrase on wikipedia, I promiss I will learn when I have some time.

Comment: OK, you don't understand why $K/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$.Firstly, you have $N \trianglelefteq K$. Then you have the element of $K/N$ is a coset of $N$ in $G$, so it is a subset of coset of $N$ in $G$. Do you got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be with definitions and notation. It is always important to remember what the symbols you are working with stand for!

In general, given a group $H$ and a subgroup $N$, we define $$H/N = \{ h + N \, | \,h \in H\},$$ where  $$h + N$$ is the left coset of $N$ corresponding to $h$, defined as $$h + N= \{h +n \, | \, n \in N \}.$$ The set $H/N$ is the set of all cosets (cosets are defined for any subgroup $N$, although the interested cases occur when $N$ is normal).

Now apply this definition to the groups in question: we want to look at the cosets of $N$ in both $G$ and $K \subset G$.

We get that

$$G/N = \{ g+ N \, | \, g \in G\},$$ and

$$K/N = \{ k + N \, | \, k \in K \} \subset G/N,$$ where the containment holds because all cosets $ k +N$ for $k \in K$ also define cosets in $G$, since $k \in K \subset G$.

Comment: Very interesting,  I perfectly understand you. In my class we defined the quotient by defining a equivalence relation ( wich is, x related to y if x plus some h on H is y) and the professor said the elements of the quotient were the "equivalence classes". This fita with what you are saying, but this way of defining gives cristal clear what really is the meat or essence of the quotient.

Answer (score 2):

$G/N$ is the set of all cosets of the form $Ng$ where $g \in G$.
$K/N$ is the set of all cosets of the form $Nk$ where $k \in K$.

Since $K \subseteq G$, then $k \in K$ implies $k \in G$.
It follows that  $Nk \in G/N$.
Hence $K/N \subseteq G/N$.

Now, if $K/N$ and $G/N$ are both groups, then we must have $K/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$.

The third isomorphism theorem tells you that this is true when 
$N \subseteq K \subseteq G$ and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.